# Import most recent data from CSV to SQL Server with SSIS

Tags: business-intelligence, ssis, bids

Here's the deal; the issue isn't with getting the CSV into SQL Server, it's getting it to work how I want it... which I guess is always the issue :)

I have a CSV file with columns like: `DATE, TIME, BARCODE, etc...`  I use a derived column transformation to concatenate the `DATE` and `TIME` into a `DATETIME` for my import into SQL Server, and I import all data into the database.  The issue is that we only get a new .CSV file every 12 hours, and for example sake we will say the .CSV is updated four times in a minute.

With the logic that we will run the job every 15 minutes, we will get a ton of overlapping data.  I imagine I will use a variable, say `LastCollectedTime` which can be pulled from my SQL database using the `MAX(READTIME)`.  My problem comes in that I only want to collect rows with a readtime more recent than that variable.

Destination table structure:
`ID, ReadTime, SubID, ...datacolumns..., LastModifiedTime` where `LastModifiedTime` has a default value of `GETDATE()` on the last insert.

Any ideas?  Remember, our readtime is a Derived Column, not sure if it matters or not.

Comment: Not in this situation, no. The vendor has it set to constantly load into the .csv for 12 hours, then start a new .csv -- it's out of our control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach that you can make use of:

Let's assume that your destination table in SQL Server is named `BarcodeData`.

1. Create a staging table *(say `BarcodeStaging`)* in your database that has the same column structure as your destination table `BarcodeData` into which CSV data is imported into.
2. In the SSIS package, add an `Execute SQL Task` before the Data Flow Task to truncate the staging table `BarcodeStaging`.
3. Import the CSV data into the staging table `BarcodeStaging` and **not** into the actual destination table.
4. Use the `MERGE` statement *(I assume that you are using SQL Server 2008 or higher version)*, to compare the staging table `BarCodeStaging` and the actual destination table `BarcodeData` using the DateTime column as the join key. If there are unmatched rows, then copy the rows from the staging table and insert them into the destination table.

Technet link to `MERGE` statement: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Hope that helps.

Comment: Worked great, thanks!  Wish it could all be done in SSIS to leave less room for errors, but for now this is a viable solution.